# Chrome: How to simulate new AutoPlay policy

Tags: google-chrome

In Google Chrome 66, autoplay policy changed.

You can read about it here:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

As a developer, I need to develop workarounds.

Of course, the first step to developing for this scenario is being able to reliably reproduce the scenario where:

- A user visits a site that does not have a significant enough MEI index.
- Autoplay is disabled unless the video is muted.

Here's my issue.

Os X, Chrome 67.0.3396.99

*Steps to Reproduce:*

1. Disable MEI detection and autoplay using ALL of the [Developer Switches](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#developer-switches)

This means:

a) Visit `chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy` and change the behavior to `Document user activation is required` and restart Chrome.
 b) Run Chrome using: `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-features=PreloadMediaEngagementData,AutoplayIgnoreWebAudio,MediaEngagementBypassAutoplayPolicies`

2. Visit a site that should allow autoplay, i.e YouTube.com

*Expected Result:*

Autoplay doesn't engage.

*Actual Result:*

It does.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that

- Step (a) appears to be unnecessary.
- When running step (b) make sure that you close Chrome entirely first. If you get the message "Created new window in existing browser session", you are in trouble.

To reiterate:

Steps To Reproduce:

1) Quit Chrome entirely.

2) Run Chrome using: `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-features=PreloadMediaEngagementData,AutoplayIgnoreWebAudio,MediaEngagementBypassAutoplayPolicies`

3) Visit YouTube.com

Result:

Video starts paused.

I've found, additionally, that my videos will still autoplay unless I click the address bar and click "enter", rather than refreshing the page.